# Error in using contains() in filter command of dplyr

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, contains

I am trying to filter the values of the column 2010. The actual column name is "Y2010". I know to get the output the easy way but i am trying to use the `function contains()` to fetch the values of the column Y2010 which are greater than 150000.

Code i used is: 
`filter(HistData, contains("2010")>150000)`

This is not working. I am getting the following error:

```
Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : 
Evaluation error: No tidyselect variables were registered.
```

I couldn't understand what I am doing wrong. 
This `contains` works fine when I use `select` command. 
`select(histdata,contains("2010")`.

Can anyone please explain what am I missing in the filter command.

Comment: Please share your data using `dput()` so others can help. 
See more here [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the "select" helpers. I was using select command helpers like ends_with, contains etc in filter command.